# django html file load image like `{{post.image.url}}`

Tags: django, django-templates, django-media

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='note/static/note/')`
```

template

`<img src={{note.image.url}}`

error:

> [14/May/2021 08:42:07] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 402
>
> Not Found: /note/static/note/test.png
>
> [14/May/2021 08:42:07] "GET /note/static/note/test.png HTTP/1.1" 404 2357

Did I do anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the `static` template tag. Something like this

```
{% load static %}

<img src="{% static 'note/test.png'%}">
```

More to this can be found here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

Comment: I don't want `<img src="{% static 'note/test.png'%}">` like.....

`{% for note in notes %}
    <img src="{{ post.image.url}}">
{% endfor %}`